# Why did South African authorities allow Cry Freedom to be screened when Steve Biko's writings were banned?

Tags: distribution, censorship, cry-freedom

*Cry Freedom* is a 1987 film about Bantu Stephen Biko. He was a black South African and an organiser and activist against the then South African apartheid regime. The film was actually shot on location in Zimbabwe and Kenya due to political turmoil in South Africa.

Quite incredibly, the film was released in South Africa despite his writings still being banned at the time of release.

**Q. Why did the South African authorities allow the release of the film despite Steve Biko's writings still being banned at the time of release?**

Answer (score 3):

### It was probably allowed initially in 1988 to avoid giving its message any status, but was quickly banned by the police afterward.

Initially the film was allowed a 1988 release by South African censors on the grounds that:

> “Even if the film was intended to evoke a revolutionary response among viewers, it fails dismally,” Kobus van Rooyen, chairman of the publications appeals board, had said in approving the film. [Source.](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1990-02-20-ca-1113-story.html)

The scornful tone of this statement suggests the South African government was trying to downplay the film and not give it the status that a banning would have bestowed on it. By that time, home video technology would have made a true banning difficult anyway. However, the police confiscated the film prints on opening day and the film was ultimately banned.

### Its successful South African release in 1990 was probably part of the government’s softening stance on Apartheid policies.

It was later [released in April 1990](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1990-02-20-ca-1113-story.html), probably as part of President F.W. de Klerk's [policies aimed at racial reconciliation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_at_the_Opening_of_the_Parliament_of_South_Africa,_1990) in that year, which of course included the February 1990 release of Nelson Mandela.

Comment: Great answer.  While researching this for my own answer I came across a book by Kobus van Rooyen, which addresses his role in liberalizing censorship in SA at the time. https://www.amazon.com/South-African-Censors-Tale/dp/1869194152

Comment: Interesting. In that light, perhaps his scornful dismissal of *Cry Freedom* was a smokescreen to get it into theaters, and the police reaction more in keeping with the government line?

Comment: Indeed perhaps so.  Of course the book is entirely from his perspective and I don't have any independent appraisal for his role or his motivation for allowing the movie into theaters.